# Out of memory exception in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

in my app i need to display images in canvas i tried using below code its working good some times.but  if play same page again and again am getting bitmap size exceeds out of memory exception.i surfed in net and i set sample size that time also am getting exception please any one help me so many days on wards i struked in this problem.

```
  Lines.class 

 public class Lines extends Activity
   {

  BitmapDrawable  sounddrawable,erasedrawable,backdrwable,fwddrwable,captiondrwable,img1drwable;
Bitmap img1bitmap,soundbitmap,eraseBitmap,backbitmap,fwdbitmap,captionbitmap;
Bitmap bitmapOrg1,bitmapOrg2,bitmapOrg3,bitmapOrg4,bitmapOrg5,bitmapOrg6,bitmapOrg;

MyView myview;
   View content;
 float screenHeight,screenWidth,screendensity;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setNoTitle();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
     screendensity = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
    Log.i("screenHeight",""+screenHeight);
    Log.i("screenWidth",""+screenWidth);
    Log.i("screendensity",""+screendensity);

         setContentView(R.layout.line);

         widtho=(int)(91*(screenWidth/1024));
     highto=(int)(175*(screenHeight/600));
    bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, widtho, highto, true);
    leftorg=(int)(120*(screenWidth/1024));
    toporg=(int)(130*(screenHeight/600));


      bitmapOrg1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.line1_2);

       width1=(int)(90*(screenWidth/1024));
        hight1=(int)(175*(screenHeight/600));
        bitmapOrg1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg1, width1, hight1, true);
      leftorg1=(int)(300*(screenWidth/1024));
       toporg1=(int)(130*(screenHeight/600));


  bitmapOrg2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.line1_3);


    bitmapOrg2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg2, widtho, highto, true);

  leftorg2=(int)(470*(screenWidth/1024));
   toporg2=(int)(130*(screenHeight/600));


           bitmapOrg3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.line1_4);
   bitmapOrg3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg3, width1, hight1, true);
              leftorg3=(int)(640*(screenWidth/1024));
  toporg3=(int)(130*(screenHeight/600));


          bitmapOrg4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.line1_5);




          bitmapOrg4 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg4, width1, hight1, true);
              leftorg4=(int)(810*(screenWidth/1024));
      toporg4=(int)(130*(screenHeight/600));



     bitmapOrg5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.line1_6);


      width6=(int)(237*(screenWidth/1024));
       hight6=(int)(139*(screenHeight/600));
            bitmapOrg5 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg5, width6, hight6, true);
leftorg5=(int)(150*(screenWidth/1024));
           toporg5=(int)(370*(screenHeight/600));


         bitmapOrg6 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.line1_7);

             bitmapOrg6 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg6, width6, hight6, true);
        leftorg6=(int)(600*(screenWidth/1024));
          toporg6=(int)(370*(screenHeight/600));

  }   
       mPaint = new Paint();

    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);

    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);

    }

     private void setNoTitle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
 private Paint       mPaint;
  private Bitmap  mBitmap;

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View
    {

            private Canvas  mCanvas;
            private Path    mPath;
            private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

             mPath = new Path();



                mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        }
         @Override
            protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
                super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

                if (mBitmap != null) {
                    mBitmap.recycle();
                    mBitmap=null;
                 }

               mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


                mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

                mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);

            }

         @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

              if(action)
              {
                  invalidate();
              }


              Paint painto = new Paint();
               painto.setAntiAlias(true);
              painto.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.magnata));

               painto.setStrokeWidth(3);
               painto.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);


                      bitmapOrg.recycle();
               canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg, leftorg, toporg, null);
               bitmapOrg1.recycle();
             canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg1, leftorg1,toporg1, null);

              bitmapOrg2.recycle();

             canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg2, leftorg2,toporg2, null);
             bitmapOrg3.recycle();
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg3, leftorg3,toporg3, null);

                bitmapOrg4.recycle();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg4, leftorg4,toporg4, null);

                bitmapOrg6.recycle();

                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg6, leftorg6,toporg6, null);

                bitmapOrg5.recycle();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg5, leftorg5,toporg5, null);

               canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);  
     } 
         private float mX, mY;
      private   float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 2;
         private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
                 mPath.reset();
                  mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                      mX = x;
            mY = y;
              }
  private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
      float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
      float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
     if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
  mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
  mX = x;
  mY = y;
   }
   }
 private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

   mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    mPath.reset();
  }

@Override
         public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX();
          float y = event.getY();

  switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      touch_start(x, y);
      invalidate();
      break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      touch_move(x, y);
      invalidate();
      break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      touch_up();
      invalidate();
      break;
      }
        return true;
}
 }
```

Comment: you should avoid initializing any object in `onDraw()` method,

Comment: have you made sure to recycle all of the bitmaps on closing the activity as well?

Comment: yes.i recycle in pause,onresume no use. and i in draw i didnt intialized in my code any thing  with out  paint object right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting an OutOfMemory error (since you didn't post the stacktrace, I'm guessing that's not the actual error that you're getting).

Your use of Bitmap.recycle() is most likely the problem. It is only meant to be used when you are discarding the bitmap, and will never reference it again. It's not actually necessary for you to call it in any case, it just causes an early cleanup of native memory that will get released when the Bitmap is finalized.

The documentation says:

> Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the
>   reference to the pixel data. This will not free the pixel data
>   synchronously; it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there
>   are no other references. The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it
>   will throw an exception if getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and
>   will draw nothing. This operation cannot be reversed, so it should
>   only be called if you are sure there are no further uses for the
>   bitmap. This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called,
>   since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no
>   more references to this bitmap.

So, you definitely should not be calling it in onDraw, and definitely not right before you try to draw the bitmap to the canvas. My suggestion is to remove all of the calls to recycle().

Comment: i want to add those bitmaps to canvas.so with out  on draw().where can i intialize those

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you don't initialize them, I'm suggesting that you stop invoking Bitmap.recyle(). It's unnecessary, and is most likely causing your problem. Just remove those statements.

Comment: i removed then also same problem